# Pros and Cons of virtualisation technology for database-server and datastorage

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Yesterday we had a chat about performance and restorability and I realized how many good things a virtualisation environment can bring to me - but as I'm a little sceptic concerning performance I'm asking here

Will a database server suffer from severe performance loss through virtualisation? I don't understand the technology to the last detail, but somehow it's a 'blackbox' more that needs to be processed through hardware. Also will disk access, with all the tricks postgis gives to us be granted (clustering, index etc.) - fragmented clustering is like no clustering!

The big advantage is maintenance and scalability. In case of a severe hardware malfunction I can migration within minutes or even realtime to another physical machine.

Who has experience and can point me to good websites or literature on this topic. I remember a few things from the last FOSSGIS and a few inhouse benchmarks on ESXi and native Servers and somehow I can't make up my mind whether it's good or not.

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable on stackexchange's database site.

Comment: Could be, but I posted it here on purpose. There are many tricks like clustering etc. to enhance performance on geospatial datasets - thought someone could've experience here.

Comment: I agree with @underdark. This would be more suited to serverfault.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. I'd like to know if there is any experience / bench marks on running GIS and spatial data on a virtual machine. I would expect that how the virtualisation software manages the database may have particular significance to spatial searches?